# State of a new Java socket

Tags: java, sockets

When I declare in Java

```
Socket s = new Socket((String)null, 12345);
```

Does this actually open a socket and use system and network resources, or is that deferred until I attach an input/output buffer? I would like to create a `Socket` object at the start of my program that is all set up to connect to the server, and just open/close it as necessary, instead of having to pass an address and port around (it seems cleaner), but not if it means the port will be open the entire time.

**EDIT**
It seems from the answers that this will not work like I wanted. How can I create a *closed* socket that is all set up with address and only needs to connect?

Comment: This way you open a socket to the loopback interface on port 12345. is this really what you want?

Comment: @kol I copied this from my testing code, which is testing against `localhost`. The final will have an actual address there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#Socket(java.lang.String,int)
,the way you are initializing your object it will be connected.

Answer (score 3):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#Socket(java.net.InetAddress,%20int) <- it depends on the constructor you use. For the constructor you have specified, it connects.

Answer (score 0):

For your edit: You will have to set up your own class that holds all setup information and can then be opened later. Maybe yüu'll just store the data in there and make a method that returns a socket. It's up to you, there's plenty ways to do that. But make sure all sockets were correctly closed at the end ;)

Answer (score 0):

Every constructor of Socket creates an underlying socket, which uses system resources, and all but the no-args constructor connect it as well, which uses network resources. There is no such operation as 'attach[ing] an input/output buffer' to a Socket.